# MongoDB javascript pass argument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, dictionary, arguments, reduce

i have a question about passing an arugment in MongoDB javascript to a map function.
Currently, what i had in mind is something like this:

```
var map = function(n) {
    if(this.x == n){
        emit(this.x);
    }
}
var reduce = function(key, values) {
    values.forEach(function(x) {
        //do something
    });
    return {nd:values};
}
db.smsdb.mapReduce(map(2), reduce, "collection")
```

But as i have tried to do this, the shell returns an error "not code"...so i'm guessing i'm not doing this the right way.
Does anyone have the right solution for this kind of problem, i would be more than glad to get it right.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
db.smsdb.mapReduce(map(2), reduce, "collection")
```

is calling `map(2)` with the result (`undefined`) being passed as the map function for `mapReduce`.

Instead do something like this:

```
db.smsdb.mapReduce(function(){ map.call(this, 2); }, reduce, "collection")
```

**UPDATE**

The above doesn't work because the `map` function isn't available in the scope the `mapReduce` map function is run.  So you have to wrap it up into a single function that can generate the map function you need:

```
var mapper = function(n) {
    function map() {
        if(this.x == n){
            emit(this.x);
        }
    }
    return map;
};
db.smsdb.mapReduce(mapper(2), reduce, "collection");
```

Comment: This doesn't return the value...i get the error Refference error:map is not defined. But does anything changes if i'm emiting 2 fields ?

Comment: @box The `map` function's return value isn't used, it's what's emitted via `emit` that matters.  You can emit as many fields as you want, but the emitted object's shape must match what your `reduce` function returns (which it currently doesn't).

Comment: I don't quite follow you, could you make an example? Please

Comment: @box See updated answer that fixes the `Reference error:map` problem.

Answer (score 1):

***scope In Mapreduce Stands For Global Parameters In Map Reduce***
As pointed out by @Dave Griffith, you can use the scope parameter of the `mapReduce` function.

I struggled a bit to figure out how to properly pass it to the function because, as pointed out by others, the documentation is not very detailed. Finally, I realised that `mapReduce` is expecting 3 parameters:

```
map function
reduce function
object with one or more of the params defined in the doc
Eventually, I arrived at the following code in Javascript:

// I define a variable external to my map and to my reduce functions
var KEYS = {STATS: "stats"};

function m() {
    // I use my global variable inside the map function
    emit(KEYS.STATS, 1);
}

function r(key, values) {
    // I use a helper function
    return sumValues(values);
}

// Helper function in the global scope
function sumValues(values) {
    var result = 0;
    values.forEach(function(value) {
        result += value;
    });
    return value;
}

db.something.mapReduce(
    m,
    r,
    {
         out: {inline: 1},
         // I use the scope param to pass in my variables and functions
         scope: {
             KEYS: 1,
             sumValues: 22// of course, you can pass function objects too
         }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
db.smsdb.mapReduce(function() { return map(2); }, reduce, "collection")
```

Comment: I get an error with your code, it says Refference error:map is not defined. Are you sure this should work ?

Comment: Thats strange. This should definitely work. It looks like the anonymous function is unable to access the map function defined before it. Is the scope of the `map` function the same as posted in your question?

Comment: Actually the map looks like this: function map(n){
                     if(this.src==n){
                        emit(this.src, this.dst);
                     }
                     }

Comment: Note that deciding what to pass to map is done for you by mapReduce. Or do you explicitly want to pass `2` every time ?

Comment: 2 would be a variable, so it could be any number

Comment: The `map` function is expected to be defined as a function accepting one argument. The `mapReduce` function decides what to pass to map in each iteration, so we usually do not have to pass it ourselves. However, if you need to override whats being passed, you can use `function() { return map(x); }` where x is the variable holding the value you need to pass to `map`. Also, note that the map should be defined in the scope that is accessible when you call `mapReduce`

Comment: Hm, so how do i define a function in the scope parameter? Shouldn't i just define an argument to map in scope:{"n":2}, like this ?

Answer (score 0):

I should also point out that this solution also works:

`var map = function() {
    if(this.x == n){
        emit(this.x);
    }
  }
  db.smsdb.mapReduce(mapper, reduce, {out:"nodes",scope:{n:2}});`